# Different output when selecting from Postgresql database table via Perl script

Tags: database, postgresql, perl

I face quite a strange situation. Via perl script i am connecting to Postgresql database and i am selecting particular columns from concrete table. The output of the SELECT query from DB is saved into File. When the script is executed second time, content of the file from the first select is moved to another file and the actual file is filled with the new select output. Then i am comparing those two files. They should be same at the time of twice script execution. Problem is, that when i run script twice to compare, they differ in one row, when i execute the script third time, the output is the same as it was in frist time and when i execute the forth time, the output is the same as was in second time, and these outputs repeatedly alternates around. I tried 4 different methods how to fetch selected rows from table into file, but still the same situation, however, the content of the table in database is still the same.

See the code below:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;
use DBD::Pg;
use File::Copy;
use File::Compare;
use List::Compare;
use MIME::Lite;
use Data::Dumper;
use Sys::Hostname;

my $qry1 = "select id, name from nms_incident_config where enable = 'f' order by name asc";
my $ltraps = '/tmp/traps.list' ;
my $ntraps = '/opt/tools/trapcfg_check/actual_traps.list';

if(-e $ntraps ) {
    print "Actual trap list exists \n";
    move("$ntraps","$ltraps") or die "Copy failed! :$!";
      };

open my $out ,">", "/opt/tools/trapcfg_check/actual_traps.list";

#connect to db and run selects for further use

my $db = DBI->connect( "dbi:Pg:dbname=<db_name>;host=localhost;","postgres", "*******", {'RaiseError' => 1});

my $qry1s = $db-> prepare("$qry1");
$qry1s->execute();
```

METHOD 1

```
  while (my @row = $qry1s -> fetchrow_array()) {
     $" = ",";
     print $out "@row \n";
  }
```

METHOD 2

```
while (my @row = $qry1s->fetchrow_array()) {
  #print $out "$row[0],$row[1]\n";
  print $out join(", ", @row), "\n"
}
```

METHOD 3

```
my ($id,$name);
$qry1s->bind_columns(\($id, $name));
while ($qry1s->fetch){
  print $out "$id, $name\n"
}
```

METHOD 4

```
my $row;
$row = $qry1s->fetchall_arrayref([]);
foreach my $r (@{$row})
{
   print $out join(", ", @{$r}), "\n";
}
```

In the scripts, only one method is uncommented and used, rest are commented.

```
$db->disconnect();

open F ,"</opt/tools/trapcfg_check/actual_traps.list" or die $!;
open F1 , "/tmp/traps.list" or die $!;

my @ntraps=<F>;
my @ltraps=<F1>;

my @lonly ;
my @nonly ;

   if ( compare( $ltraps,$ntraps ) == 0 ) {
      print "Files are same \n" ;
      die "Files are same\n";
      };

   if ( compare( $ltraps,$ntraps ) ne 0 ) { print "Files are different\n";

      my $tc = List::Compare->new(\@ltraps, \@ntraps );
         @lonly = $tc->get_complement;
#        @nonly = $tc->get_unique;
      print "Different row/s in new trap list: "."@lonly\n";

   };
```

Outputs >

```
# ./tcheck_2.pl
Actual trap list exists

Files are same
Files are same

# cat /opt/tools/trapcfg_check/actual_traps.list | grep -i 2147590214
2147590214, wlsxStaUnAssociatedFromUnsecureAP

# cat /tmp/traps.list | grep -i 2147590214
2147590214, wlsxStaUnAssociatedFromUnsecur

# ./tcheck_2.pl
Actual trap list exists

Files are different
Different row/s in new trap list: 2147590214, wlsxStaUnAssociatedFromUnsecur

# cat /opt/tools/trapcfg_check/actual_traps.list | grep -i 2147590214
2147590214, wlsxStaUnAssociatedFromUnsecur

# cat /tmp/traps.list | grep -i 2147590214
2147590214, wlsxStaUnAssociatedFromUnsecureAP

# ./tcheck_2.pl
Actual trap list exists

Files are same
Files are same

# cat /opt/tools/trapcfg_check/actual_traps.list | grep -i 2147590214
2147590214, wlsxStaUnAssociatedFromUnsecureAP

# cat /tmp/traps.list | grep -i 2147590214
2147590214, wlsxStaUnAssociatedFromUnsecur

# ./tcheck_2.pl
Actual trap list exists

Files are different
Different row/s in new trap list: 2147590214, wlsxStaUnAssociatedFromUnsecur

# cat /opt/tools/trapcfg_check/actual_traps.list | grep -i 2147590214
2147590214, wlsxStaUnAssociatedFromUnsecur

# cat /tmp/traps.list | grep -i 2147590214
2147590214, wlsxStaUnAssociatedFromUnsecureAP
```

Can you help me ? :)
Thanks

Best Regards
Jaro

Comment: Is there any more to your program than what you show? Where in the output is the line with the missing `eAP`—is it at the end of the file? Try `close $out` after the `print` loop.

Comment: You should set `PrintError => 0` as well as `RaiseError => 1`; you don't want a warning as well as an error that both say the same thing.

Comment: Are you sure `nms_incident_config` is a regular table and not a view?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[As Borodin suggested in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42575446/different-output-when-selecting-from-postgresql-database-table-via-perl-script/42651580#comment72284985_42575446), I needed to add

```
close $out
```

after the `print` loop.